# Fetch Datatype Size PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm fetching data from a PostgreSQL database. All is working fine, however i want to select the size of the data_type as well however i cant get that to work. Please help Here's my query:

```
 $result2 = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT table_name as tabela, column_name as campo, data_type as tipo from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql works fine.

I'd say you user does not have permission (Read) to the table(s) its asking to view ?

You could try this

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA PUBLIC TO youruser;
```

For the size of the column you could you the System Administration Function

```
pg_column_size(data_type)
```

> " pg_column_size(any) returns an **int** Which is the Number of bytes used to store a particular value (possibly compressed) "

```
SELECT table_name as tabela, column_name as campo, 
data_type as tipo,pg_column_size(data_type) as tipo1 from
information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public'
```

Results

[image: Postgresql Results set using pg_column_size]

Ref [Postgresql 9.5 section 9.26. System Administration Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html)

All the best

Comment: i know my sql works fine, but i want something like

column_length as length to get the size of the field... if thats possible :(

Comment: Hi @Boltz0r  I hope this is what you're looking for? All the best

Comment: I'm not sure if he gives me the size of the type itself or the size of "integer" f ex.... but that's something ;) I'll count that as solved :D Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Boltz0r  pg_column_size(any)  returns an int  Which is the Number of bytes used to store a particular value (possibly compressed)